# echo html tag value separately for different block

Tags: php, dom

I was trying to get username, title, comment count and video count from html source code. There are few blocks which each contains different details for this parameters. Here is code which scrap data but issue is it scrap all of them in list.

Like first all video count, then all comments count and so on. Not for each block separate. [Consider this link](http://dv.youku.com/ycwj?from=y1.3-dv-ycpd-239-10221.90876-90721.0-1) for source code.

here is the code:

```
function getParameter($url)
{
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    if($html)
    {   
        //we iterate all 'div.v' and select data from every 'div.v' separately
        $containersDiv = $html->find('div.v'); 
        foreach($containersDiv as $div) 
        {
            $containers1 = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] div.v-meta-entry'); 
            foreach($containers1 as $container)
            {               
                $plays = $container->find('.v-num'); // get nos of time video played
                $item = new stdClass();
                foreach($plays as $play)
                {
                    $nos = $play->plaintext; 
                }
                //echo $address;
            }
             $containers2 = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] a'); //get user name
            foreach($containers2 as $username)
            {
                $user = $username->plaintext;
            }
             $containers3 = $div->find('div.v-link a'); //get video title
            foreach($containers3 as $title)
            {
                $title = $title->plaintext;
            }
            $commentcontainers = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] div.v-meta-entry span'); //get nos of comments changed
            foreach($commentcontainer as $cont)
            {
                $comments = $cont->plaintext;
            }
        }

        return $data;               
    }
}
```

also there is issue at `$commentcontainers = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] div.v-meta-entry span');`. It gives `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I appreciate help if someone tell me where is issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this function, output:

```
new div -------------------

450万 
Mini剧-乙方甲方
我还以为你要抢鸡蛋呢
843 
new div -------------------

134万 
万万没想到
<万万没想到>雪藏篇
470 
new div -------------------

236万 
曾经想火
闺蜜的情人竟是我老板
422 
new div -------------------

641万 
暴走漫画
日版“周董”来华拍电影
3,959 
new div -------------------

695万 
Mini剧-乙方甲方
<乙方甲方>唐僧爱上90后
1,242 
new div -------------------
```

---

```
function getParameter($url)
{

    $html = file_get_html($url);

    if($html)
    {   

        //we iterate all 'div.v' and select data from every 'div.v' separately
        $containersDiv = $html->find('div.v'); 
        foreach($containersDiv as $div) 
        {
            echo "new div -------------------</br></br>";
            $timevideo = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] div.v-meta-entry span', 0); 
            $nos = $timevideo->plaintext; 
            echo $nos."</br>";

            $containers2 = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] a.v-username', 0); //get user name
            $user = $containers2->plaintext;
            echo $user."</br>";

            $containers3 = $div->find('div.v-link a', 0); //get video title
            $title = $containers3->title;
            echo $title."</br>";

            $comments = $div->find('div[class=v-meta va] div.v-meta-entry span', 1); 
            $comments_count = $comments->plaintext; // comments count
            echo $comments_count."</br>";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `$div->find('div.v-link a', 0);` here what does `0` indicates?

Comment: This is number element in array, `0` - first element, `1` - second, etc. There contains few <a> tags.